# Trying to replace a value in a URL on click

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am trying to replace a word in a URL with a value that is set in the CMS

I have created a function to do this which will replace the word "DOMAIN" with the set value in the CMS. I can get the console to log the correct value but when you click the link it ignores the second part of the domain name.

for example if i enter the word "MIKE" then click the link I would want it to return "http://www.crazydomains.com.au/domain-names/search/?tld=.com&domain=mike"

This is what i have so fare I can get the console to log "?tld=.com&domain=mike" but not add it to the URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var parseOutboundLink = function(url, v, d) {
   if (d != '') {
    v = v.replace('+DOMAIN+', d);
    console.log(v);
   }                
}

<a href="http://www.crazydomains.com.au/domain-names/search/?tld=.com&domain=+DOMAIN+" onclick="parseOutboundLink('http://www.crazydomains.com.au/domain-names/search/?tld=.com&domain=+DOMAIN+', '?tld=.com&domain=+DOMAIN+', document.getElementById('domain').value); return;" target="_blank">
TEST LINK    
</a>
```

Comment: Is there a PHP part to this, or did you mistag it?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that remained was to actually change the href:

```
var parseOutboundLink = function(url, v, d) {
    if (d != '') {
        v = v.replace('+DOMAIN+', d);
        this.setAttribute("href",v); //this points to the event emitter here
    }                
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help e-neko, Do I also need to change the value of 'this'? I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functiondomain-availability:79 parseOutboundLinkdomain-availability:217 onclick"